# What's the _all_dependencies_are_recorded flag used for in JVM

Tags: jvm

it was comment as follow，but I can't find any usage of this flag

```
  // Flag to indicate if the compiler has recorded all dependencies. When the
  // can_redefine_classes capability is enabled in the OnLoad phase then the compiler
  // records all dependencies from startup. However if the capability is first
  // enabled some time later then the dependencies recorded by the compiler
  // are incomplete. This flag is used by RedefineClasses to know if the
  // dependency information is complete or not.
  static bool _all_dependencies_are_recorded;
```

searched the jvm codebase, but found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the cited comment, the flag is used to determine if `RedefineClasses` needs to deoptimize only compiled methods that depend on the class being redefined (if `_all_dependencies_are_recorded == true`) or to deoptimize all compiled methods otherwise (if not all nmethod dependencies are recorded).

The flag is checked in [VM_RedefineClasses::flush_dependent_code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/729ae1d78716a3830837e49376b5340eb60f9449/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvmtiRedefineClasses.cpp#L4082-L4089):

```
  // This is the first redefinition, mark all the nmethods for deoptimization
  if (!JvmtiExport::all_dependencies_are_recorded()) {
    CodeCache::mark_all_nmethods_for_evol_deoptimization(&deopt_scope);
    log_debug(redefine, class, nmethod)("Marked all nmethods for deopt");
  } else {
    CodeCache::mark_dependents_for_evol_deoptimization(&deopt_scope);
    log_debug(redefine, class, nmethod)("Marked dependent nmethods for deopt");
  }
```

Find more details on the underlying problem in [JDK-8324241](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8324241).

A recent fix for this issue adds the JVM flag `-XX:+AlwaysRecordEvolDependencies` (on by default) which forces the JVM to record all nmethod dependencies unconditionally from the very beginning. Once this new behavior is always enabled, there will be no need for the `_all_dependencies_are_recorded` flag.

Comment: If the recording is not complete, how to find all the methods that need to be deoptimized when aggressive CHA optimization encounters a new class loading?

Comment: @bug_lee Dependencies for speculative optimizations are always recorded.